# hiding table row when checkbox clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this Table ,and fetching row using this php code ,when i click on  this checkbox one alert message is shown ,if user click on ok button of that alert, than i want to hide that perticular row. [image: check box is shown in image]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="height: 25px">NAME</th>
        <th style="height: 25px">EMAIL</th>
        <th style="height: 25px">CELL NO</th>
        <th style="height: 25px">CITY</th>                   
        <th>Hide Candidate</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
while($data_set1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$data_set1['ename']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data_set1['eemail']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data_set1['ecell']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$data_set1['ecity']}</td>";

    echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"hide_cand\" id=\"hide_cand\" onclick=\"return confirm('This action can not be recovered, are you sure you want to HIDE this Candidate? ')\"/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a function from the `onclick` instead, passing in the checkbox element. In the function, you can hide it's parent `<tr>` (row) element.

```
echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"hide_cand\" id=\"hide_cand\" onclick=\" return hideRow(this)\"/></td>";
```

Javascript:

```
function hideRow(checkbox)
{
    if(confirm('This action can not be recovered, are you sure you want to HIDE this Candidate? '))
    {
        checkbox.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Using this row is getting hidden ,but only temporary ,how to hide it permanently?

Comment: @raj, if you need to persist it to a data source then that would probably be better as a new question with specific details (such as db system etc etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your_chk_id').live('click', function(){
  $(this).parent('tr').hide();
});
```

Comment: i got solved my query ,thanks for your answer ,but i dont know how can i insert it in my code .

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function hiderow(check)
{
if(confirm('This action can not be recovered, are you sure you want to HIDE this Candidate? '))
    {
        check.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
      <td>   <input type="checkbox" name="row_2" onclick="return hiderow(this)" />  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
      <td> <input type="checkbox" name="row_2" onclick="return hiderow(this)" />  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Delete first row in the table</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the input field like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hide_cand" id="hide_cand" onclick="return confirmation(this); return false;"/>
```

And after that add this script to your page it should work :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function confirmation(item) {
  var answer = confirm("This action can not be recovered, are you sure you want to HIDE this Candidate?")
  if (answer){
    alert("confirmed yes!")
            item.parent().parent().hide();
 }
 else{
    alert("confirmed no!")
 }
}
//-->
</script>
```